# converting imageAsset to base64 (nativescript-vue)

Tags: android, vue.js, android-camera, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

want to convert the imageAsset to base64.
sample code below,
methods: {

```
    takePicture() {
        camera.takePicture({ width: 300, height: 300, keepAspectRatio: true, saveToGallery: false})
            .then(imageAsset => {

                this.pictureFromCamera = imageAsset;
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = imageAsset;
                console.log(imageAsset);
```

Comment: What is the type of your imageAsset, is it a file or src?

Comment: @VaibhavSingh it's src

Comment: A possible duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/6678237